# Show div after scroll and hide when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a div which needs to be shown when a user scrolls 400 pixels down. When he scroll back up, above the 400 pixels, this div needs to be hidden again. I can make this work with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut(`) but in this case I want to add a small animation similar to `slideUp()` by using the animate(). But doing it this way makes it very buggy, sometimes it will appear, other times not.

Why is this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3k28r/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scroll` is too frequent.
Suggest you use `setInterval` to check scrollTop.

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6K6Dt/)**

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function update() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $('.signup_scroll').animate({
            "bottom": '0px'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $('.signup_scroll').animate({
            "bottom": '-90px'
        }, 300);
    }
}

setInterval(update, 500);
```